# Creating an Array of UICollectionViews for PageViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I have set up a CollectionViewController, that will create a CollectionView from a datasource. Now I want to use a PageViewController to swipe trough the CollectionViews but I don't know how I to create an array that contains the CollectionViews.

So far I only presented one of the CollectionViews the following way:

```
let CollectionVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionView") as! CollectionViewController
    CollectionVC.itemStrings = matrixArray[0].makeString()
    CollectionVC.columns = problem.columns
    CollectionVC.rows = problem.rows
    self.present(CollectionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And that worked just fine to present one View.

But now I need to create an array that can be read by the PageViewController to generate the PageView, how do I do that? Im not even sure about the format it needs to be for the PageViewController Datasource, as far as I can see from other tutorials, its supposed to be an array of UIViewController and not of Type UICollectionViewController as I planned to do, if thats the case, how can I make that work with the CollectionViews?

Any advice on how to create such an Array that can be used as datasource for the PageViewController?

***For more Clarification***

Here is a picture of how it is supposed to look at the end:

[image: CollectionView]

Every Screen is basically created by the CollectionViewController and the PageViewController is organize them and make it possible to Swipe trough these screens as indicated by the pagination.

//Edit:

Thanks Puneet Sharma for the answer. Im sure this is already very close to the solution I was looking for. But since I am a total self-taught noob in programming, Im not completely sure where to fit in all this information.

So far I have 2 Controllers, one ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

//Initialize Variables:
var matrixArray = Array<Matrix>()
var basicArray = Array<Array<Int>>()
var maxArray = Array<Double>()
var currentSolutionArray = Array<Array<Double>>()
var isOptimal = false
var isCyceling = false
var CollectionViewArray: [UICollectionView] = []

//The outlets are for later
@IBOutlet weak var myObjectionFunction: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var myConstraint1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myConstraint1RightSide: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var myConstraint2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myConstraint2RightSide: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var myConstraint3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myConstraint3RightSide: UITextField!


//StartButton
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {

    //Initializing Objection Function
    let objFunction = [-40.0,-30.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]

    // Initializing Nr. of Rows and Columns of the Matrix
    let rows = 4
    let columns = 6

    // Initializing constraints
    let constraint0 = [1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,8.0]
    let constraint1 = [2.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0]
    let constraint2 = [2.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,18.0]

    //Initalize an Array containing all constraints
    let constraints = [constraint0, constraint1, constraint2]

    //Alternative for use of UserData -> Delete objFuntion, rows, columns, constraint0..2, constraintsArray
    //let problem = getData().0
    //let constraints = getData.1
    let problem = LinearProblem.createLP(rows: rows, columns: columns, objFunction: objFunction, constraints: constraints)


    // Initializing Current solution (No need to change anything)
    let currentSolution = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: constraints.count)



    print("Initial Problem: ")
    print(problem)
    print("\n")


   let solution = PrimalSimplex(problem: problem, currentSolution: currentSolution)

    matrixArray = solution.0
    basicArray = solution.1
    maxArray = solution.2
    currentSolutionArray = solution.3
    isOptimal = solution.4
    isCyceling = solution.5

    let CollectionVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionView") as! CollectionViewController
    CollectionVC.itemStrings = matrixArray[0].makeString()
    CollectionVC.columns = problem.columns
    CollectionVC.rows = problem.rows
    self.present(CollectionVC, animated: true, completion: nil) 
 }
}
```

It is basically a screen with a start button, that starts the algorithm when its pushed and presents the next View.

And then this CollectionViewController:

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    //Is also set in Storyboard
    let reuseIdentifier = "cell" 

    var itemStrings: Array<String?> = []
    var rows: Int = 0
    var columns: Int = 0   


//
//Setup CollectionView: Table to display LPs including Datasource
//

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    let newPath = indexPath.item + 1
    print("You selected cell #\(newPath)")
}

// calculate height and width of cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = collectionView.bounds.width
    let gaps = columns-1

    let tmpWidth = width - CGFloat(gaps)
    let itemWidth = tmpWidth / CGFloat(columns)

    let height = collectionView.bounds.height

    let tmpHeight = height - CGFloat(gaps)
    let itemHeight = tmpHeight / CGFloat(rows)

    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}

// CellSpacing vertical
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return CGFloat(3)
}

// CellSpacing horizontal
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return CGFloat(1)
}

// change background color when user touches cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    //Change color
    if cell?.backgroundColor == UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.40, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0) {
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.94, blue:0.94, alpha:1.0)
    }
    else{
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.40, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0)
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let numberOfItems = rows*columns
    return numberOfItems
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cel

    cell.myLabel.text = itemStrings[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.94, blue:0.94, alpha:1.0)

    // Change shape of cells
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    return cell
 }
}
```

These are currently also the only elements in my Storyboard.

I suppose I need to add the PageViewController in the Storyboard and fill it with the code form you of the HomeViewController. Then change the segue in the storyboard from the start button to the HomeViewController.

The parts I didnt understand are the ChildVCs that will be created. Do I need to add that part to my ViewController? And what about the IndexedCollectionViewController class, do I need to create an extra file for that or can I fit that into my collectionView somewhere?

And what about this function

```
private func viewController(atIndex index:Int) -> IndexedCollectionViewController
```

where does that go? I think in my case that would be in the ViewController class and Id just call the method in the start button ?

Sorry for all these pretty simple questions, but as a self taught coder its sometimes hard to grasp the concepts behind things ^^

Comment: Is your UICollectionView scrolling horizontally?

Comment: Not scrolling at all. It has a maximum of 6 rows/colums of cells that only contain numbers. So the CollectionView always fits on the screen. The picture i added at the end shows a Table in the middle. Thats the collectionView.

Comment: Do you need to show the sceen with the start button or straightaway show the pageview?

Comment: First the page with the start button (later this will be the Data Entry Page, and the PageView will present a Step-by-Step Solution). So Startbutton Page is InitialVC, pushing the start button will then present the PageVC with that contains the CollectionViewVCs... Thats the idea behind it. Not sure if it works that way tough...

Comment: Then you should introduce another ViewController that has a pageviewcontroller and present it from inside startButton(_ sender: Any) method. You don't need to present collectionviewcontroller now. In this new viewcontroller you can use the code I have written in the HomeViewController. Also, pass on the matrix array to this viewcontroller. I am assuming this matrix array will contain datasource for all your collectionviewcontrollers. viewController(atIndex index:Int) method is just a utility method that gives collectionviewcontroller to the pageview datasource.

Comment: What about the insertChildViewController and the IndexedCollectionViewController ? Do I need to implement them in a separate file or can i add them to the existing ViewController/CollectionViewController?

Comment: You dont need to segregate them but it is advisable to do it. I create a separate folder for Extensions and Subclasses in my projects. But if you dont want it, there is no need to.

Comment: I added the insertChildVC to my VC and that seems to work so far. But where do I put the IndexedCollectionVC? I tried a new Cocoa Touch Class, but then XCode wanted me to make a completely new CollectionViewController class. I don't know what you mean by subclass for the CollectionViewController. How can I do that?

Comment: I tried to add the index to my CollectionViewController, like a normal variable and I replaced your IndexedCollectionVC with CollectionViewController in the code. I get an SIGABRT Error when I click the start button, because its not possible to cast UIPageViewController to PageViewController (I did it the same way as in the code above in the ViewController, right at the end let PageVC = storyboard?.istantiate....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my view, [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller) documentation is a little vague.
The point of contention is the existence of a method:

```
func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, 
              direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection, 
               animated: Bool, 
             completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

All the tutorials pass one one view controller in this array and they are right of-course. But because of the existence of this method, I assumed I could give all view controllers, that needed to be shown, in an array to pageviewcontroller.

But, this method actually is needed to pass the view controllers that needs to be shown after the animation. If we need to show more than one view(view controllers) on screen, we can pass those views inside the array. But that is seldom the case, hence all tutorials show passing of a single VC inside the array.

[UIPageViewControllerDatasource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdatasource) is used to provide additional view controllers.

You can implement your viewcontroller that hold pageviewcontroller in tis way.

```
// Extension on UIViewController to insert child view controller
extension UIViewController {

    func insertChildController(_ childController: UIViewController, intoParentView parentView: UIView) {
        childController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)

        self.addChildViewController(childController)
        childController.view.frame = parentView.bounds
        parentView.addSubview(childController.view)

        childController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

}

// Subclass of UICollectionViewController to create IndexedCollectionViewController. This is done to introduce an integer property to index collectionview controllers
class IndexedCollectionViewController:UICollectionViewController {
    var index:Int = 0
}


class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var pageViewController:UIPageViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addPageViewController()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

// MARK:- PageView
extension HomeViewController:UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    fileprivate func addPageViewController() {
        if !self.isViewLoaded {
            return
        }

        self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.horizontal, options: nil)

        let firstVC = self.viewController(atIndex: 0)
        pageViewController.setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        pageViewController.dataSource = self
        pageViewController.delegate = self
        self.insertChildController(pageViewController, intoParentView: self.view)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = (viewController as! IndexedCollectionViewController).index
        index = index+1
        return self.viewController(atIndex: index)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = (viewController as! IndexedCollectionViewController).index
        if(index == 0){return nil}
        index = index-1
        return self.viewController(atIndex: index)
    }

    // Method that creates viewcontroller
    private func viewController(atIndex index:Int) -> IndexedCollectionViewController {

        // This method will work only if you change the Class of CollectionViewController to IndexedCollectionViewController in your storyboard
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionView") as! IndexedCollectionViewController
        vc.itemStrings = matrixArray[index].makeString()
        vc.index = index
        vc.columns = problem.columns
        vc.rows = problem.rows
        return vc
    }
}
```

In my view, your view layouts should look something like this.
**VC1** :-> view controller which has start button, and will present vc2.
**VC2** :-> view controller which shows pageview.
 
It can either be a PageViewController itself(as UIPageViewController is subclass of UIViewController) or a simple ViewController with PageViewController added as a child VC.

PageViewController, essentially shows other ViewControllers content, in form of pages. These other viecontrollers in your case is CollectionViewController.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I set up such an array that contains the ViewControllers that I want?


I have an array that contains the data for the Table MatrixArray[ ] and usually I just give these data to the CollectionViewController and the present-function will create the next View and initiate the segue.


But now I need to create several Views, with the data from the MatrixArray elements. How to I create these Views and how do I store them in an array thats compatible with the PageViewControllerDatasource Protocol?

Comment: Thanks again, I think that I didnt make it clear where my actual problem is. I know that I need to implement these functions. But to implement them I need to give them an array to work with, that contains the Views. My problem is, that I don't know how to create an array that contains the Views that the CollectionViewController creates. Or how do I store the CVCs themselves in an array (they all create a View with different Data)?

Comment: @Bepa1012: I have edited the answer with code and comments on how you can implement pageviewcontroller datasource. I hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I also edited my question because I still don't fully understand the answer. Its hard to transfer code from others to my specific case, because I am so yet unexpirienced :(

Comment: Was wondering if you could take another look on the question, if you find the time. Id really appreciate some help. I wrote the current status in a comment on the original question. Pretty much stuck at this at the moment...

Comment: @Bepa1012: I have edited the answer. I hope it helps you.